# Set control panel site link to open in new window

Tags: control-panel

Is there a way to set the upper right hand website link in the CP to open in a new window or tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CP CSS & JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) add-on ([download link](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/cp_css_js)) to inject JS to add the attribute to the link?

```
$('#navigationTabs .msm_sites a').attr("target", "_blank");
```

Tested on EE v2.9.2 & v2.5.3. Don't worry about the msm reference - it's marked as that even if you don't have MSM installed.

Comment: That addon hasn't had a commit in 4 years, which makes me weary, but if you've tested it and it works, than your answer is cleaner than mine. Upvote!

Comment: It's not a complex add-on, so no need to fix or improve. Pixelandtonic are a good development agency too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading a custom theme, and modifying the Javascript includes for that theme. All you should need to add to that file is this line:

```
$( '.first_level:last-of-type' ).attr('target', '_blank');
```

And that should hit the last button on your top level menu, which will be the redirect link to your site. Good luck!

*ps* this was tested in EE 2.5, not 2.9+, but I doubt they've changed class names in the CP when still in the same version. Subversion changes like that would break theme compatibility too badly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
You could edit menu.php file.
It's located in system/expressionengine/libraries folder.
You must go to the line 321 and change it so:

$menu_string .= $this->_process_menu(array('help' => $this->generate_help_link()), 0, TRUE, '', 'external');

Byez